# Django-postgresql: psycopg2 dsn takes wrong password

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am running `python 2.7.3` and `django 1.5.1` with `postgresql DB`. After setting up a simple django app  I am getting a `OperationalError at FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`. When I checked the local variables I found that psycopg2 connection is taking in the wrong password. I had specified the correct password in the django settings.py file. 
Also `manage.py syncdb` works fine, and this problem shows up 2 out 3 times.

All authentication methods in `pg_hba.conf` is set to `md5 and settings.py` has `HOST`: `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the user postgres to do that.

Create a user and a db for your app, and use that user only for that.

```
su
su postgres
createuser -P <dbusername>
:type and re-type <dbuserpasswd>
createdb -O <dbusername> <dbname>
```

Check your `pg_hba.conf`

```
local   all    all    md5
```

Restart your postgresql server.

Check your Django Settings

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'dbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
    'USER': 'dbusername',
    'PASSWORD': 'dbuserpasswd',
    'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Restart your http server.